# Integrating Catch2 Unit Tests to a project which is structured with tests close to each library

Tags: c++, unit-testing, cmake, catch2

```bash
project-root
├── build
├── cmake
├── main
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   └── main.cpp
├── src
│   ├── app
│   │   ├── inc
│   │   │   └── app
│   │   │       ├── appLib.hpp
│   │   │       └── appMain.hpp
│   │   ├── src
│   │   │   ├── appLib.cpp
│   │   │   └── appMain.cpp
│   │   └── test
│   │       └── CMakeLists.txt
│       │   └── test_appLib.cpp
│   ├── common
│   │   ├── inc
│   │   │   └── common
│   │   │       └── utility.hpp
│   │   └── test
│   └── core
│       ├── inc
│       │   └── core
│       │       └── coreLib.hpp
│       ├── src
│       │   └── coreLib.cpp
│       ├── test
│       │   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│       │   └── test_coreLib.cpp
│       └── CMakeLists.txt
├── testRunner
│   ├── build
│   └── CMakeLists.txt
├── ThirdParty
└── CMakeLists.txt
```

I'm trying to integrate *unit tests* to my project, so I decided to use project structure shown above. My point is to keep test and app binaries separated, and keeping test codes close to production code, aligning with [Craig Scott's recommended approach](https://discourse.cmake.org/t/project-structure-for-unit-testing-and-coverage/9038/2#:%7E:text=I%20would%20recommend%20keeping%20unit%20tests%20close%20to%20the%20code%20they%20are%20testing.%20In%20your%20scenario%2C%20that%20would%20mean%20putting%20unit%20tests%20with%20each%20module.).

I'm using `Catch2` as a unit test library, and it's cloned under `ThirdParty` dir. I can build my application binary from `root/build`, and tests from `testRunner/build`. But the problem is there is several binaries for each test directory. I want to make a single test binary for all test codes. I have to use single `add_executable` command in a higher level, but how to do that while using `Catch2::Catch2WithMain`?

root/CMakeLists.txt:

```bash
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.5)

# set the build type
if(NOT CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE)
    set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release)
endif(NOT CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE)

if(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE MATCHES Debug)
  message("Debug build.")
elseif(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE MATCHES Release)
  message("Release build.")
endif()

set(application_name "cmake-project-template")
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(application_version "1.0.2")
set(PROJECT_VER ${application_version})

cmake_policy(SET CMP0048 NEW)
cmake_policy(SET CMP0079 NEW)

project (${application_name} LANGUAGES C CXX)

# set search path for CMake modules
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/Modules)
find_package(PCAP REQUIRED)
find_package(MysqlConnectorCpp REQUIRED)
add_subdirectory(ThirdParty)
add_subdirectory(src)
add_subdirectory(main)
```

testRunner/CMakeLists.txt:

```bash
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.5)

set(application_name "TEST-cmake-project-template")
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(application_version "1.0.2")
set(PROJECT_VER ${application_version})

cmake_policy(SET CMP0048 NEW)
cmake_policy(SET CMP0079 NEW)

project (${application_name} LANGUAGES C CXX)

# set search path for CMake modules
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../cmake/Modules)
find_package(PCAP REQUIRED)
find_package(MysqlConnectorCpp REQUIRED)

# Include Catch2 from ThirdParty
add_subdirectory(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../ThirdParty/Catch2 build/Cathc2)
add_subdirectory(../ThirdParty build)

# enable testing
enable_testing()

# Add your test directories
add_subdirectory(../src/app/test app_test)
add_subdirectory(../src/core/test core_test)
add_subdirectory(../src src_test)
```

main/CMakeLists.txt:

```bash
set(source
    main.cpp
)

add_library(main ${source})

target_link_libraries(main PUBLIC app core)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} app core)
```

src/CMakeLists.txt:

```bash
add_subdirectory(app)
add_subdirectory(common)
add_subdirectory(core)
```

src/core/CMakeLists.txt:

```bash
set(source
    src/coreLib.cpp
)

add_library(core ${source})

target_include_directories(core PUBLIC inc)
target_include_directories(core PRIVATE inc/core)

target_include_directories(core PUBLIC ${MYSQLCONNECTORCPP_INCLUDE_DIR})

target_link_libraries(core PUBLIC
                            common
                            ${MYSQLCONNECTORCPP_LIBRARY} )
```

src/core/test/CMakeLists.txt:

```bash
add_executable(test_core test_coreLib.cpp)

target_include_directories(test_core PRIVATE ../inc)
target_include_directories(test_core PRIVATE ../inc/core)

# Link with the core library target
target_link_libraries(test_core PRIVATE core Catch2::Catch2WithMain)

add_test(
    NAME test_coreLib
    COMMAND test_coreLib
)
```

src/app/test/CMakeLists.txt:

```bash
add_executable(test_app test_appLib.cpp)

target_include_directories(test_app PRIVATE ../inc)
target_include_directories(test_app PRIVATE ../inc/core)

# Link with the app library target
target_link_libraries(test_app PRIVATE app Catch2::Catch2WithMain)

add_test(
    NAME test_app
    COMMAND test_app
)
```

src/core/test/test_coreLib.cpp:

```cpp
#include <catch2/catch_test_macros.hpp>
#include "core/coreLib.hpp"

TEST_CASE("coreLibFoo1", "[coreLib]")
{
    coreLibClass x;
    x.coreLibfoo1();
}
```